# Deciphering text for body while sending email

Tags: python

I am trying to sendmail using python,am saving the body in variable "body"I try to decipher it using below but the body of the email stays as is,html code is not getting decoded..I looked at other posts on stackoverflow but couldnt get anything substantial...where is it going wrong?

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def email (body,subject):
    msg = MIMEText("%s" % body)
    msg["From"] = "test@company.com"
    msg["To"] = "bot@qualcomm.com"
    msg["Subject"] = 'The contents of %s' % subject
    p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t"], stdin=PIPE)
    p.communicate(msg.as_string())
def main ():
    subject="Test subject"
    body = """\
        <html>
         <head></head>
         <body>
          <p>Hi!<br>
              How are you?<br>
             Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
         </p>
         </body>
        </html>
"""
    email(body,subject)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Body is getting printed as follows as is..html code is not getting decoded

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p>Hi!<br>
      How are you?<br>
     Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
 </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at what: `msg = MIMEText("%s",body)` is doing (ie, think about string interpolation)

Comment: @JonClements - Thanks,it should have been     msg = MIMEText("%s" % body)

Comment: @JonClements - Now am seeing the body is not getting decoded in html format..body is getting printed as is...updated question with the same

Comment: what do you mean "decoded"?  it looks like what you sent...

Comment: @TokenMacGuy - E-mail is sent in outlook,i still see html tags in the message body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh... so you want the MUA to interpret the content as html.  Set the content-type in the message:

```
msg["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
```

Otherwise, the MUA will assume it is `text/plain`, and render it as such.